# java compatibility on HP Unix

Tags: java, hp-ux

Is java on HP Unix a clone of an existing JDK implementation (oracle, IBM etc.) or is it a new implementation? 
Do I have to fear any compatibility issues on HP-UX?

Comment: If they write to the JVM spec, it should be compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from [hp website](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=HPUXJDKJRE70) jdk-for-hp-ux has release all the patch updates released by JDK.

Following is the extract from  [refernce pdf](http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02645654/c02645654.pdf)'s overview:

> The following tables list HP's SDK and JDK versions and equivalent
>   Oracle release. Note that when an Equivalent Oracle Release is listed,
>   it includes all previous Oracle drops